# How to update tables in many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I have two entities in a many-to-many relationship and 3 tables:

- Customer
- Shop
- CustomerAndShopAssignemnt (join table)

I have list of shops for example:

```
ShopA, ShopB, ShopC, ShopD
```

and I want to add a new Customer, for which I choose 2 shops (for example ShopA and ShopC).

What I do is:

```
var listOfChoosenChops = // get the shops entities from db by ID's

var newCustomer = new Customer()
{
   Name = "Martin",
   Age = 44,
   Shops = listOfChoosenChops 
}

_context.Customers.Add(newCustomer)
_context.SaveChanges();
```

I get error from EF that it can't put the entities with the same primary keys. That means that EF tries to store new `Shops` into the database.

My question is: how to solve it and update only join table?

PS: I saw another posts but I'm not able to find solution which will help me there.

Comment: I'm also wrestling with this at the moment.  You should include your models for customer and shops.  (I found that EF creates the join table with Table1Name+Table2Name plural)  But I was getting an odd SQL error (something about threads and XABORT when using .add() on the list) I've found so many different methods posted I think I'm just going to do it the old school way.  (So remove the lists from the models and set the IDs in the join table manually...)  It'd be nice to see a definitive method for CRUD with many to many.  (use the new hashset thing in model? fluent API stuff required??)

Comment: You should better to include your error message as well. In addition, Could you please include your model class for Customer, Shop and CustomerAndShopAssignemnt table along with your database schema?

Comment: You should start from one principal table and add the relationship data using the list in the principal table

Answer (score 0):

You should have provide more information. by the way.

Here is the updated code:-

```
var existingShops = _context.Shops.Where(s => s.ShopId == shopId).ToList();

var newCustomer = new Customer()
{
   Name = "Martin",
   Age = 44
};

newCustomer.Shops = existingShops;

_context.Customers.Add(newCustomer);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add a new Customer, for which I choose 2 shops (for example
> ShopA and ShopC).

I have a suggestion like below:

```
var ShopA = // get the ShopA from db by ID
var ShopC = // get the ShopC from db by ID
var newCustomer = new Customer()
{
   Name = "Martin",
   Age = 44,
};
newCustomer.Shops.Add(ShopA);
newCustomer.Shops.Add(ShopC);
_context.Customers.Add(newCustomer)
_context.SaveChanges();
```

My demo code like:

```
            var s1 = _context.Supplier.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SupplierID == 1);
            var s2 = _context.Supplier.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SupplierID == 2);
            var newCustomer = new Product()
            {
                ProductName = "p3",
             
            };
            newCustomer.Supplier.Add(s1);
            newCustomer.Supplier.Add(s2);
            _context.Product.Add(newCustomer);
            _context.SaveChanges();
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Typically when I see this error, it's due to using the AsNoTracking method.

If you're using the AsNoTracking method when getting your list of shops, removing that method should solve your error.